# Como retornar o que o cliente comprou/pagou?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho as seguintes tabelas: utilizando JOIN

```
 CREATE TABLE tbCliente
( ClienteID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ClienteNome VARCHAR(50),
  ClienteTelefone VARCHAR(15),
  ClienteDataCadastro DATE)

 CREATE TABLE tbPagamento
( PagamentoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ClienteID INT,
  PedidoID INT,
  PagamentoValor DECIMAL(8,2),
  PagamentoData DATE)

CREATE TABLE tbPedido
( PedidoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PedidoData DATE,
  ClienteID INT)

CREATE TABLE tbProduto
( ProdutoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ProdutoNome VARCHAR(50),
  ProdutoValor DECIMAL(5,2))

CREATE TABLE tbPedidoItem
( PedidoItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PedidoID INT,
  ProdutoID INT)

ALTER TABLE tbPagamento  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPagamento_tbCliente
FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES tbCliente (ClienteID)

ALTER TABLE tbPagamento  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPagamento_tbPedido
FOREIGN KEY(PedidoID) REFERENCES tbPedido (PedidoID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedido  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedido_tbCliente
FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES tbCliente (ClienteID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedidoItem  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedidoItem_tbPedido
FOREIGN KEY(PedidoID) REFERENCES tbPedido (PedidoID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedidoItem  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedidoItem_tbProduto
FOREIGN KEY(ProdutoID) REFERENCES tbProduto (ProdutoID)
```

Comment: Poderia acrescentar detalhes sobre o leiaute do resultado? O que solicitou está muito vago. Por exemplo, para cada cliente é para retornar item a item ou venda a venda? Ou é para retornar somente valores totais de cada cliente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braian, eis esboço do código que retorna o valor de cada pedido de cada cliente e o que já foi pago de cada pedido.

```
-- código #1
with 
Valor_Pedido_Cliente as (
SELECT Pd.ClienteID, Pd.PedidoID, 
       sum (Pr.ProdutoValor) as soma_Pedido
  from tbPedido as Pd
       inner join tbPedidoItem as PI on PI.PedidoID = Pd.PedidoID
       inner join tbProduto as Pr on Pr.ProdutoID = PI.ProdutoID
  group by Pd.ClienteID, Pd.PedidoID
),
Valor_Pgto_Cliente as (
SELECT Pg.ClienteID, Pg.PedidoID,
       sum (PagamentoValor) as soma_Pgto
  from tbPagamento as Pg
  group by Pg.ClienteID, Pg.PedidoID
)
SELECT T3.ClienteID, T3.ClienteNome, T3.ClienteTelefone,
       T1.PedidoID, T1.soma_Pedido, 
       coalesce (T2.soma_Pgto, 0) as soma_Pgto
  from Cliente as T3
       inner join Valor_Pedido_Cliente as T1 on T1.ClienteID = T3.ClienteID
       left join Valor_Pgto_Cliente as T2 on T2.ClienteID = T1.ClientID
                                             and T2.PedidoID = T1.PedidoID;
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

A primeira CTE, `Valor_Pedido_Cliente`, calcula o valor total de cada pedido. 
A segunda CTE, `Valor_Pgto_Cliente`, retorna o que cada cliente pagou, de cada pedido. 
A junção do retorno das duas CTE gera o relatório final.

O código foi construído de maneira modular, conforme artigo “[Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/programacao-modular-com-expressoes-de-tabela-cte/)”.

Comment: Funcionou de primeira, muito obrigado pela ajuda!